# Python - difficulty login to a website

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, python-requests

I am new to python and programming and would really appreciate any help here. 
I am trying to login to [this](https://www.dell.com/sts/passive/commercial/v1/US/en/RC1362592/Premier/Login/Recognized?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%253a%252f%252fwww.dell.com&wreply=https%253a%252f%252fwww.dell.com%252fidentity%252fv2%252fredirect%252f&wctx=rm%253d0%2526id%253dpassive%2526clienturl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.dell.com%252faccount%252f) website using the below code and I just cannot go beyond the first page.

Below is the code I have been trying...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://www.dell.com/sts/passive/commercial/v1/us/en/19/Premier/Login/Anonymous?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%253a%252f%252fwww.dell.com&wreply=https%253a%252f%252fwww.dell.com%252fidentity%252fv2%252fRedirect')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
formtoken = soup.find('input', {'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'}).get('value')

payload = {'UserName' = username, 'Password'=password, '__RequestVerificationToken': formtoken}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.dell.com/sts/passive/commercial/v1/us/en/19/Premier/Login/Anonymous?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%253a%252f%252fwww.dell.com&wreply=https%253a%252f%252fwww.dell.com%252fidentity%252fv2%252fRedirect', data=payload, headers=headers)
    r = s.get('http://www.dell.com/account/', headers=headers)
    print r.text
```

I am just not able to go beyond the login page. What parameters apart from login. I also tried checking the form data in the Chrome dev tool but that is encrypted. [Form Data - Dev Tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSzZh.png)

Any help here is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have edited the code to pass token in the payload as suggested below. But I have no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are not following a correct approach for making a POST request.

Steps which you can follow:

1. First make a GET request with your URL.
2. Extract access token from the response.
3. Use that access token for your post request.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did exactly that after you suggested but to no avail.